# Check of work method in the Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, nunit

I have a controller in which the method, upon receiving of an error sending a letter (email). How in the tests verify the success of sending the letter without changing the controller itself and the method.

```
 if (Error){
     _mailService.SendAdminMail("Error");
 }
```

I write Tests on NUnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, and others can correct me, if you write NUnits to test a functionality like sending a mail, you are increasing dependecies on your NUnit test. Think for example, on your continuous integration environment, when your tests are running at that moment, the n/w is gone. If you have written NUnits to verify sending of emails, all those tests would fail.

It's one of the reason why we mock databases when we write NUnits. We test functionalities with mock objects.

What I think is you should mock the sending of emails and write NUnits against it to test whether on error an email is sent or not.

Comment: So I must mock (_mailService) and then writing tests for it separately?